# Unity3D/C# - Async Loading of assets and level causes framedrop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to load a level with a few large assets in Unity 3D, and I can't get rid of stutters and lagging while the content is being loaded.

I divided my main scene in separate sub-levels, and I'm loading them asynchronously.

So first I'm attempting to pre-load the actual assets from the resources folder :

```
private IEnumerator preLoadAsset(string assetPath)
{
    ResourceRequest asyncLoad = Resources.LoadAsync(assetPath);
    yield return asyncLoad;
    asyncLoadedAssetsCount += 1;
    preloadSceneAssets();
}
```

This step finishes fast with very little impact on performance.

```
private IEnumerator LoadYourAsyncScene(string sceneName)
{
    AsyncOperation asyncLoad = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneName, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
    asyncLoad.allowSceneActivation = true;
    yield return asyncLoad;
    asyncLoadedScenesCount += 1;
    loadAdditiveScenes();
}
```

Most the lagging happens here, whether I set the scene activation to true or false.

I also set the background loading priority of the app to Low earlier in the script :

```
 Application.backgroundLoadingPriority = ThreadPriority.Low;
```

What am I doing wrong? 
Is it even helping to pre-load the assets before loading the additive scene on top, and if not, how can I make use of the pre-loading of the assets in memory efficiently?

*Note : the additive scenes are empty except one large asset in each one of them, and no Start/OnEnable/Awake functions are executed*

Comment: Not sure how correct this answer is but I found this exact Q&A here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/130180/smooth-loading-screen-between-scenes

Comment: Instead of Coroutines you should get into [async / await](http://www.stevevermeulen.com/index.php/2017/09/using-async-await-in-unity3d-2017/) because Coroutines are only kind of a "fake" async but still running on the same thread.

Comment: @derHugo the issue there seems like it's impossible to call anything from the Unity API (like scene loading) from outside the main thread. `UnityException: LoadAsyncInternal can only be called from the main thread.` - Also, using async/await in the main thread actually freezes even more the execution of the app than before when I used coroutines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asynchronous scene loading works only at the stage of loading an asset from a hard disk.
Next comes Merge Prefabs, it is he who creates this problem.

Source: Profiler Data

Solution:
Instantiate prefabs manually using the GameObject.Instantiate